# Failed: sendKeysToActiveElement error while invoking sendKeys to ENTER and other keystrokes using ChromeDriver Chrome with Protractor

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

My Protractor tests that use sendKeys to press Enter or Tab failed today after I was auto-updated to Chrome 76.

This worked find yesterday on Chrome 75.

This is the code that used to work:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB).perform();
```

The error message is

```
Failed: sendKeysToActiveElement 
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
    System info: host: 'DESKTOP-6JGLC4V', ip: '192.168.0.5', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Our Angular application has drop-down menus where you have to click outside of the drop-down or press the Tab key to close it. So I'm not sending the key stroke to an input element. I've tried `$('body').sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: So ... when the browser updated to 76, did you update the driver also?

Comment: @JeffC Yes, as I was troubleshooting I did a webdriver-manager clean, reinstalled Protractor, then did webdriver-manager update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
Failed: sendKeysToActiveElement
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to invoke `sendKeys()` to the *ActiveElement*.

This issue started to surface when *ChromeDriver* / *Chrome* switched over to **W3C** support.

@AutomatedTester in the discussion [UnsupportedOperationError: sendKeysToActiveElement with sendkeys](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1179) mentions, this may be an issue within the *Actions* class within the *Client* bindings.

> There should be a little shim in the bindings that make sure the same functionality is given on older commands that have been removed. This has been implemented in the core selenium binding.

- The *Python* [example](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py#L343-L356):

  ```
  def send_keys(self, *keys_to_send):
  """
  Sends keys to current focused element.
  :Args:
   - keys_to_send: The keys to send.  Modifier keys constants can be found in the
     'Keys' class.
  """
  typing = keys_to_typing(keys_to_send)
  if self._driver.w3c:
      for key in typing:
      self.key_down(key)
      self.key_up(key)
  else:
      self._actions.append(lambda: self._driver.execute(
      Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ACTIVE_ELEMENT, {'value': typing}))
  return self

  def send_keys_to_element(self, element, *keys_to_send):
  """
  Sends keys to an element.
  :Args:
   - element: The element to send keys.
   - keys_to_send: The keys to send.  Modifier keys constants can be found in the
     'Keys' class.
  """
  self.click(element)
  self.send_keys(*keys_to_send)
  return self
  ```

---

### Solution

@barancev have already merged the required changes through the commit [Renaming back 'py' directory, use of 'legacy_create_init' argument](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/b300c358f65f33c0cf43177316f433601c027bdb) and this issue would get completely resolved with the next release of *ChromeDriver v77.0* / *Chrome v77.0*.

The good news is *ChromeDriver v77.0* is already released containing the following fixes. From the [Release Notes of ChromeDriver v77.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.10/notes.txt):

- Resolved issue 2975: Webdriver Actions for keys (CONTROL, SHIFT etc..) not working in ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.8 [Pri-2]
- Resolved issue 2981: Chromedriver in W3C mode loses mouse state between Actions API calls [Pri-2]

---

### Outro

[Protractor.Key.Enter is not working in ChromeDriver v75.0.3770.8](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5274)

Comment: Thank you @DebanjanB. Based on this [comment](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5274#issuecomment-519986467), do you think this may also be related to the fix they will have in Chrome 77?

Comment: @JosephMutidjo Check out the answer update and let me know the status.

Answer (score 2):

Upgraded to chromeDriver 77 and still running into the same issue as mentioned above.
`await elem.sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);` also tried: `await browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB).perform();`

```
`- Failed: sendKeysToActiveElement
  Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
  System info: host: 'GC02XYZ...', ip: 'fe80:xyz...', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '11.0.1'
  Driver info: driver.version: unknown`

`chromeDriver -v
ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40`
```

Comment: Just updated and it's still not working for me either. There's a workaround by turning off w3c - https://support.govizzle.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000038432-At-the-beginning-of-a-student-lesson-we-get-a-popup-that-says-Scan-How-can-we-get-rid-of-this-

Comment: Thanks Joseph - that helped!

Comment: CORRECTION - Just updated and it's still not working for me either. There's a workaround by turning off w3c - https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5285

Answer (score 2):

When using **chrome 74+** please add the below at configuration.js file

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress : 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['spec.js'],
    capabilities:{
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'goog:chromeOptions': {
            w3c: false
        }
    }

};
```

Notes:
refer the this link
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5274#issuecomment-522258213